# Multiple case condition in sql order by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

How to make conditional ordering for two or more columns..I just tried the below code. is there any better way of writing this?

```
CASE WHEN  d.receipt IS NULL AND c.receipt =1 then pr.account END ASC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =1 AND c.receipt IS NULL then pr.account END ASC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =1 AND c.receipt =0 then pr.account END ASC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =1 AND c.receipt =1 then pr.account END ASC,

CASE WHEN  d.receipt IS NULL AND c.receipt IS NULL THEN pr.amount END DESC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt IS NULL AND c.receipt =0 THEN pr.amount END DESC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =0 AND c.receipt IS NULL THEN pr.amount END DESC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =0 AND c.receipt =0 THEN pr.amount END DESC,
CASE WHEN  d.receipt =0 AND c.receipt =1 THEN pr.amount END DESC
```

Comment: It seems that the columns `d.receipt` and `c.receipt` can only have values `0, 1 and NULL`. Do you confirm this?

Comment: yes you are correct..that columns can have only 0,1 and NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
CASE WHEN d.receipt = 1 THEN pr.account
     WHEN d.receipt = 0 THEN -pr.amount
     WHEN c.receipt = 1 THEN pr.account
     ELSE                    -pr.amount
END
```

It always sorts ascending but in some cases on the negative amount which of course results in descending.

The manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html says:

"Each WHEN clause search_condition expression is evaluated until one is true, at which point its corresponding THEN clause statement_list executes. If no search_condition is equal, the ELSE clause statement_list executes, if there is one."

This implies that the expressions are evaluated in the order they are specified.
In other words, the 3rd condition (`c.receipt = 1`) is evaluated only if `d.receipt` is NULL.

Comment: I have updated my question with my different scenarios. Could you please check and confirm if your answer will work for that..

Comment: I updated the answer, considering the fact you sort on either account or amount. It should work though I didn't try.

Comment: Yes.. i have checked its fine..Thank you so much

Comment: Could you confirm one thing if  -pr.amount means order by amount descending?

Comment: Ordering ascending the negative value means ordering descending the positive value.